# Is it possbile to know whether a user updated status or not in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Say I have 10k users for my app. Now, I would like to know whether a particular person updated a status message!

How does Facebook provide such calls and whats the best way to update the databases (they store keywords for public status messages)

Comment: @JoranBeasley okay, how can I efficiently perform graph api requests for all 10k users behind the scenes to update databases.. I wish things to work as dynamic as "Twitter Trends"

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe to [Facebook Real-time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) by sending a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/subscriptions` with a parameter `object` that has the value `user` and a parameter `fields` that has the value `statuses`.

You will also need to provide

- a `callback_url` on which facebook will perform a GET request to verify the subscription and POST requests for the actual updates and
- an opaque `verify_token` that will be echoed to your `callback_url` to verify the subscription,